# Difference between two queries 'select statement' with alias table name

Tags: sql, sql-server, alias

I want to ask about the difference between these two queries:

`select ProductName = case when p.ProductID is null then 'Unknown' else p.ProductName end`

and

`select p.ProductName = case when p.ProductID is null then 'Unknown' else p.ProductName end`

(p is an alias for table Product)

What is the difference between them in sql server management studio 2008 R2? When I executed the first one, it was executed succesfully, but for the second one I got an error message "Incorrect syntax near '='."

Anyone can explain me about this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the first case `ProductName` is not a table column, it is an *alias*. think of it like this:

```
select case when p.ProductID is null then 'Unknown' else p.ProductName end as ProductName
```

in the second incorrect query you are trying to do something illegal because you are trying to both select a column from a table and assign to it as if it were an alias you are generating from an expression.

I think your confusion is that you think `ProductName` is always a column because there is a column with that name in that table, but in this context `ProductName` is *not* a column name; it is an *alias* for the case statement results. so when you try `p.ProductName` you are telling the SQL engine to select the `ProductName` column from the `p` table and then you try to assign a case statement as if it were an alias (which it isn't in the `p.ProductName` context).

you could just as easily use *any* name for the case statement since it is an alias. you could do:

```
select DerivedProductName = case when p.ProductID is null then 'Unknown' else p.ProductName end
```

does that example make it more clear that you aren't dealing with column names when you use this syntax?

Comment: Then, how about this? SELECT   ProductNumber, Category =
      CASE ProductLine
         WHEN 'R' THEN 'Road'
         ELSE 'Not for sale'
      END, FROM ...
it's the same format as my second query, isn't it? It also select and assign a value to it..I took this query from Microsoft website.

Comment: @SQLnubie No, it is not the same as your broken query. if you change `Category =` to `something.Category =` you will get the error. please update your question if you need farther clarification.

Comment: Oh, I mean 'Category' here is also a column right? and it also does both selecting and assigning a value to that 'Category' column, just like my second query. Please correct me if i'm wrong bcause I'm still a bit confused.

Comment: @SQLnubie see my updated answer for a more detailed explanation about why `ProductName` and `Category` are _not_ table columns in this context.

Comment: Ah, I got it! Thanks so much for your detail explanation. And yes, all this time I don't know it's actually an alias. By the way, in the query about 'Category' above, is the 'ProductLine' will also be displayed? Or it's just a column for WHEN condition and will not be displayed in the output?

Comment: @SQLnubie the only things that will appear in a result set are things in the select clause. in the case of that query you will get `ProductNumber` and `Category` where `Category` is derived from ProductLine. this is a separate question and you should ask another if you need answers unrelated to this question. if this answer has answered your original question please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Oh, sorry.. I'm also newbie in this forum. Thank you for your explanation regarding my questions and your reminder, really appreciate it. :) I also have marked your answer as accepted.